# How to hide background image on mobile devices (SP Page Builder)

Tags: css

I am currently working on a website using Joomla and I am using SP Page Builder extension to construct my content pages. I have a background image on one of these content pages and it just messes up the mobile display of the webpage so i want hide the background image on mobile devices. I have used this css code which has worked for me before (on pages without SP Page Builder) but it seems not to be working, here is the code:

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
section.sppb-section.bg {
background-color: #ffffff;
background-image: none;
}
}
```

here is the auto generated HTML code of the element with a background image:

[This is a screenshot of page the layout of a row with two columns, somehow this row and columns are constructed using `<div></div>` tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEYkD.png)

Is there a solution to this or a work around. Thank You.

Comment: The `background-image` property probably gets overriden by the builder's CSS. Try `background-image: none !important;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html you have inline style which force the background to be there so you will need to use `!important` to force background-image to be none

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    section.sppb-section.bg {
        background-color: #ffffff  !important;
        background-image: none !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have the background image display on screens > 768px, not the other way around.

```
.bg {
background:#fff;
}
@media screen and (min-width:768px){
.bg {
background-image:url(img.jpg);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline CSS is always take preference over external css that's why your css code is not working. Try to keep that inline css style code in external css file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the bg image is being added in the style attribute which will override your css class. You'll need to decorate your css with important.

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
section.bg {
background-color: #ffffff !important;
background-image: none !important;
}
}
```